# Combine XmlNodelist

Tags: c#, xmlnodelist

Can any one please give me a solution to combine xmlNodelists to a single list .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use LINQ's `.Concat` method. The problem is that `XmlNodeList` is `IEnumerable` as opposed to `IEnumerable< XmlNode >`. Thus you have to call `.Cast< XmlNode >` on your `XmlNodeLists`.

For example:

```
   var List = nodesoriginal.Cast<XmlNode>().Concat<XmlNode>(nodesupdate.Cast<XmlNode>());
```

Comment: how do i convert the singleList back into XmlNodeList - simple Casting doesnt seem to work

Comment: Hello, I tried the above, but the "Concat" method is not available for some reason. I have imported System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq. Please help!

Comment: You have to include the generic type: var List = nodesoriginal.Cast<XmlNode>().Concat<XmlNode>(nodesupdate.Cast<XmlNode>());